# How can i use Dockerfile in Docker swarm?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker swarm in windows Server Core 2016
I'm trying to create containers using docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml

#

this is my YML file :

```
version: "3"
services:
db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
    networks: 
       - cpxnet2           
    deploy:         
       environment:
          - SA_PASSWORD=Abcd1234
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y         
web:
    image: microsoft/iis:latest
    build: .
    networks: 
       - cpxnet2                 
    deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
                memory: 500M    
    ports:
     -  "800:80"
    depends_on:
        - db  
networks: 
    cpxnet2:
```

#

this is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM microsoft/iis:latest
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ./index.html /index.html
```

#

this is my Container content after creating :

Directory: C:\inetpub\wwwroot

> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
>   ----                -------------         ------ ----
>   -a----        3/13/2019  10:56 AM            703 iisstart.htm
>   -a----        3/13/2019  10:56 AM          99710 iisstart.png

it should at least delete old files and copy my index.html file 
but this doesn't happen !! what should i do ?

thank you for support !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `build` in docker-compose.yml when using the compose-file in a `docker stack deploy` command. So what happens is that it takes the image `microsoft/iis:latest` and ignores the `build`.

Have a look at the official docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

> Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with
>   a (version 3) Compose file. The docker stack command accepts only
>   pre-built images.

What you have to do is build your image before running the `docker stack deploy` command and then use `image` with your image's name.